# Choose all labels in a Grafana time series chart in one go instead of "Ctrl+click"-picking each label until the full list is marked?

Tags: grafana

In a time-series chart in Grafana, I try to mark a bunch of labels so that all of their curves are shown.

As a default, I get only four labels' curves in the graph, but I have dozens of labels and I do not want to mark everything with the mouse, it takes too much time and nerves.

The idea is likely that choosing too many curves will leave you lost in the lines. But in this case, the graph is about finding outliers, strong changes and trends, or just high numbers. You can hover over any curve that might catch your eye, and that is all. Thus, having 80 curves in one graph is no problem.

The filter is just about shrinking the list, not about marking all labels in it. I can use it to Regex-check for queries with 2-digit seconds duration and some other filter on the query_name.

[image]

Yet, I just want to see all labels' curves in one go, and not just by clicking like in the following:

[image]

Is there a trick to get this done? Perhaps even by using the Grafana Dashboard code to mark the jobs as a hardcoded list? Or is there a shortcut or other trick to pick all?

Comment: windows usually supports native selection by ctrl click and ctrg move that mean you can mark an area while ctrl is pressed

Comment: @djdomi Marking everything while scrolling or moving marks the text of the labels, but there is no way to click on this block as a whole, any click will just click the chosen line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Click and un-click the label is all you need.

There is an easy solution for this. You need to click on just one of the labels, so that only that one is chosen. Then click on it again. This will mark all labels.

## Old workarounds (not needed)

There does not seem to be a way to mark all with a shortcut or click-trick.

##### Workaround 1 (best choice)

1. Make a filter for just *one label* (`=` and a random label) of the many labels of which you wish they were all marked. *You do not need to click on the label below the panel's graph above, but you can, the next steps work in both cases.*
2. Delete the filter again by clicking on the trash symbol.
3. Hold `Ctrl` and then double-click below the panel's graph the *one label*. You need to do this before the panel has reloaded all labels.
4. All labels will be marked.

[image]

##### Workaround 2

Choose a label filter in your panel query that leads to few labels which you can `Ctrl+click` quickly. To get the few labels, I used a regex: `=~ .*some_word.*` on the query_name which has the labels that I want to fully mark. After marking all of the labels at hand (here two), I just delete the filter again. And the setting of marking everything will be taken over to anything without that filter.

[image]

##### Workaround 3

Another trick that worked was to duplicate another panel where everything is marked and change that again to what you want. But the tricks above are easier, no need to duplicate a panel for this.